# How to get the rendered PHP+HTML codes into a text file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a file which is combination of PHP and HTML.

How can i get the plain HTML code output from this file into a text file? or either put it into the text box.

The code of my form, which i use to generate an HTML form can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/cWPGPLxW)

Comment: Leo I am able to understand your First Question, what exactly are you looking for? in First Question?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized because you're asking two very specific questions here. Please ask only one question per post, and please try to post the minimal amount of code required to explain the problem.

Comment: i have generate a html form, but i need to get the html plain code, with php <?echo ?>...

Comment: still didnt get you Leo... :(

Comment: sorry i will ask for question one and deleted the code not require

Comment: sorry for confusing you, when i develop the form , it use the php , so the code have some php part e.g. <? echo "$set['formName'];?>, but i would like a file have  the actual value and plain php code eg. formName1 instead of php code <? echo "$set['formName'];?>, can i do that?

Comment: You need to have a HTML form in one file and a PHP code in seperate file so that the manupilation will be done in PHP code and HTML will be used to communicate with user.... so whenever your form is submitted from above mention HTML page its action needs to be in a PHP processing file to process the data, If I am wrong in interpreting your question let me know...

Comment: or , simply speaking, how can i write the output html form in a html file? will the php code write into that text (html) file?

Comment: But i need to have some value display using echo?

Comment: Answer Given by @Starx might help you out if that what you are looking for

Comment: In That case the first point given By @Starx will suit your need

Comment: Thanks for your answering OM, but if i write it to the text file, will i also include the php code e.g. <? php echo ......?> in the text file?

Comment: @LeoChan, I edited the question to make it more understandable to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

It seems OP is asking about **HOW to get the rendered PHP+HTML codes into a text file?**

```
//get the output from the file
ob_start();
include "yourphpplushtml.php";
$output = ob_get_clean();

//now create a text file and write to it
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $output); //put the output
fclose($fp); //close the handler

//Or put it into the textare

echo '<textarea>'.$output.'</textarea>';
```

---

<sub>Previous Answer But may be helpful to others too</sub>

There are many ways HTML can be combined with PHP

1. Output HTML directly from PHP

   ```
   <?php
      echo "<head><title>my new title</title></head>";
   ?>
   ```
2. Include PHP inside you HTML

   ```
   <title><?php echo $dynamictitle; ?></title>
   ```
3. Or even separate them in old fashioned complicated way

   ```
   <?php if($resultFound == true) { ?>
       <p> The result was successfully found.</p>
   <?php } ?>
   ```

Comment: Thank you , simply speaking , the code listed in my question is some php+ html , if i want to get the actual value  of it( instead of a variable) and store all the code + value into a text file, can i do this?